# How to create new blocks for theorems

Tags: beamer

I was trying to create two different blocks: one for 'Quiz' and other for 'Homework'. The following MWE looks quite OK:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\usepackage{thmtools}

\newcounter{qzcounter}
\newcounter{hwcounter}

\declaretheoremstyle[
title = Quiz \arabic{qzcounter} ,
]{qzstyle}


\declaretheoremstyle[
title = Homework \arabic{hwcounter} ,
]{hwstyle}

\declaretheorem[style=qzstyle]{qz}
\declaretheorem[style=hwstyle]{hw}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{qz}
Q 1
\end{qz}

\begin{qz}
Q 2
\end{qz}

\begin{hw}
HW 1
\end{hw}


\begin{qz}
Q 3
\end{qz}

\begin{hw}
HW 2
\end{hw}


\begin{qz}
Q 4
\end{qz}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

But, the two things I failed to do:

1. Automatic numbering for the quizzes and homeworks separately
2. Changing the block type (say, `exampleblock` for 'Homework' and `alertblock` for 'Quiz')

Comment: you need to add \stepcounter{qzcounter} before \arabic{qzcounter}

Comment: If the quiz/homework environments should be referencable, then `\refstepcounter{qzcounter}` is to be used

Comment: `\stepcounter` does not work as it is in the mwe given by the OP, maybe the `thmtools` package has its own way of dealing with counters.

Answer (score 2):

You're using `beamer` and `beamer` provides its own mechanism to declare new `theorem` environments. It's explained in `beameruserguide`, section 12.4.

The main command is:

```
\newtheorem{<environment name>}[<numbered as>]{<head text>}[<number within>]
```

which in your case could be

```
\newtheorem{qz}[qzcounter]{Quiz}
\newtheorem{hw}[hwcounter]{Homework}
```

with `qzcounter` and `hwcounter` previously declared.
By default, beamer doesn't show numbers in theorem headers, but `\setbeamertemplate{theorems}[numbered]` will do it.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
%\usepackage{thmtools}

\newcounter{qzcounter}
\newcounter{hwcounter}

\newtheorem{qz}[qzcounter]{Quiz}
\newtheorem{hw}[hwcounter]{Homework}

\setbeamertemplate{theorems}[numbered]

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{qz}
Q 1
\end{qz}

\begin{qz}
Q 2
\end{qz}

\begin{hw}
HW 1
\end{hw}


\begin{qz}
Q 3
\end{qz}

\begin{hw}
HW 2
\end{hw}


\begin{qz}
Q 4
\end{qz}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

This solves 1. Let me some time to [try to solve 2.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/211445/1952) ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why you're using any theorem package if you're bypassing the numbering mechanisms… `beamer` suggests that if you define theorems with theoremstyle X active, it will try to put it into a `Xblock` environment instead of plain block, but it will only do that for `example`. We seem to have split that into [a separate question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/211445/1860) now.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\setbeamertemplate{theorems}[numbered]

\declaretheorem[title=Quiz]{qz}

\theoremstyle{example}
\declaretheorem[title=Homework]{hw}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{qz}Q 1\end{qz}
\begin{qz}Q 2\end{qz}
\begin{hw}HW 1\end{hw}
\begin{qz}Q 3\end{qz}
\begin{hw}HW 2\end{hw}
\begin{qz}Q 4\end{qz}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```