# How to define different colors for different theorem-like environments in beamer

Tags: beamer, theorems

After reading section 12.4 Theorem Environments from `beameruserguide` I understand that all theorem like environments (theorem, lemma, corollary, ...) except example use same `beamertemplate` which means same block colors. Is it true?

If the answer is yes, is there any beamer (not using `tcolorbox` or `mdframed` theorems) way to customizing colors for each environment?

If the answer is no, could you show me an example?

Nex there's a little code to start with:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{theorem}[A]
Theorem body
\end{theorem}

\begin{example}[B]
Example body
\end{example}

\begin{proof}[C]
Proof body
\end{proof}

\begin{lemma}[D]
Lemma body
\end{lemma}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start the answer small: as you will have found in the docs, the actual environment inserted depends on the value of `\inserttheoremblockenv`. 
Unfortunately, the docs only do what the docs say:

> if a theorem that has theorem style example is typeset, it will
>   expand to exampleblock

and not what they might seem to suggest (i.e. something along the lines of "if the style is X, and environment `Xblock` exists, I'll use `Xblock`, otherwise `block`). The way this is done is simplistic (beamerbasetheorems.sty):

```
  \def\th@example{%
    \normalfont % body font
    \def\inserttheoremblockenv{exampleblock}
  }
```

`\th@example` is the macro that stores the look and layout of theorem style `example`. So for a different style, you can change the environment.

Defining an environment for the color combinations you want seems to be done best in a brute-force way by adapting the definition of, e.g. `exampleblock` (`beamerbaselocalstructure.tex`):

```
\newenvironment<>{exampleblock}[1]{%
    \begin{actionenv}#2%
      \def\insertblocktitle{#1}%
      \par%
      \mode<presentation>{%\usebeamerfont{block}%
        \setbeamercolor{local structure}{parent=example text}}%
      \usebeamertemplate{block example begin}}
    {\par%
      \usebeamertemplate{block example end}%
    \end{actionenv}}
```

On first thought, though, this won't help you with the pre-defined theorem names, so you might want to give the class option`notheorems` to disable the predefined `theorem` etc. and define them yourself.